# Flutter/Firestore- Retrieving product information issue

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to load all of my product data from firestore. I have a data schema:

```
class SingleProduct with ChangeNotifier {
  static const EVENT = "event";
  static const IMGURL = "imgUrl";
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const PRICE = "price";

//Private Variables
  String _event;
  String _imgUrl;
  String _name;
  double _price;

// getters
  String get event => _event;
  String get imgUrl => _imgUrl;
  String get name => _name;
  double get price => _price;


  SingleProduct.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
      _event = snapshot.data()[EVENT];
  _imgUrl = snapshot.data()[IMGURL];
  _name = snapshot.data()[NAME];
  _price = snapshot.data()[PRICE];}
  }
```

I have then created a class to map all the data received to a list of products:

```
class ProductServices {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  String collection = 'products';

  Future<List<SingleProduct>> getAllProducts() async =>
      _firestore.collection(collection).get().then((snap) {
        print(snap.docs.length); // returns 11 products as expected
        List<SingleProduct> allProducts = [];
        snap.docs.map((snapshot) =>
            allProducts.add(SingleProduct.fromSnapshot(snapshot)));
        print(allProducts.length); //returns 0 so I think my map isn't working
        return allProducts;
      });
}
```

The Firestore query returns 11 query snapshots as expected but I then try and add them to a list using my product schema but the the results show the list has 0 elements. Any suggestions how to map the results of my fire base query to a list?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what exactly isn't working the way you expect.  We don't really know what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach()`:

```
snap.docs.forEach((snapshot) => allProducts.add(SingleProduct.fromSnapshot(snapshot)));
```

---

**Explanation time:** [tl;dr Your lambda wasn't executed at all]

[`map()` is a lazy function](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) intended for transforming elements in a list, which works only if the result is going to be used.

In your code, the result of `map()` is nowhere used later (eg. assigned to a variable), which is why the lambda within it is not called (why would it transform if the transformation is not used ahead?)

Also, it's not apt for your use-case.

To demonstrate its laziness, try running this code in DartPad:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ["a", "b", "c"];
  List<String> anotherList = [];
  var mappingOutput = list.map((element) { anotherList.add(element); return element + "X"; }).toList();
  print(list);
  print(mappingOutput);
  print(anotherList);
}
```

Notice that the result of `map()` is to be given back to a variable mandatorily, which pushes the laziness aside and executes it.

`anotherList` will be filled.